# Using adjective's て form as "and"

Tags: grammar, syntax, て-form

I know that your can connect to adjectives with the て form, for example,

僕の彼女は美しくて優しいです。 My girfriend is beautiful and kind

but can you follow that て with a continuation of the sentence, for example,

僕の彼女は美しくて僕が醜いなのに、僕が好きです。 My girlfriend is beautiful, and despite my being ugly, she likes me.

Comment: 醜い is an I-adj, you don't need to put **な** after it. **僕が** seems redundant for me...

Comment: By the way, Japanese speakers often use a meaningless `～のこと` to mark the [nominative object](https://books.google.com/books?id=4CS07LRO8O8C&hl=ja&pg=PA141#v=onepage) of `好き`.  It serves as a grammatical marker of objecthood.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can. For example, 彼女は優しくて、彼女の母も優しいのに、僕は彼女とは結婚したくない. However you may omit て.

And 僕の彼女は美しくて僕は醜いのに、彼女は僕(のこと)が好きです would be more natural.

Comment: For your examples... Is the saying "My girlfriend is kind, and even though her mother is also kind... I wouldn't want to marry her." the same with "Even though my girlfriend is kind and her mother is also kind, I wouldn't want to marry her."? My point is that does the のに also cover the first sentence [僕の彼女は美しい] [今日は雨が降っている] [彼女は優しい]?

Comment: @Dekiru Yes, it does.